# Returning List of Java Objects from Spring 4 Controller to AJAX

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, serialization

I am using AJAX to fetch a list of `Company` objects from database. I have added @ResponseBody to my controller method. And `jackson-mapper-asl` dependency. Below is AJAX call:

```
$.ajax({
        type : 'GET',
        url : $("#contextpath").val() + '/getCompanyList',
        success : function(response) {
            alert(response);
        }
    });
```

Controller method:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/getCompanyList", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody List<Company> getCompanyList() {
    logger.debug("reached controller getCompanyList");
    return companyServices.getCompanyList();
}
```

But I am getting error

> No converter found for return value of type: class java.util.ArrayList

Secondly, Is there a way to return list of Java objects to AJAX without converting it to JSON ?

Answer (score 2):

> But I am getting error

looks like you are missing an Ajax lib (Jackson for example) or the converter is not registered, maybe the mime type (mapping) is missing

> Is there a way to return list of Java objects to AJAX without converting it to JSON ?

For conversation between an server and a client, it is required that that transferted date is serialized into some format and the client deserialize it. (Typical formats are Json, XML, and many different binary formats). For AJAX it is common to use JSON (not so often XML). To answer your question: you could use an other format (for example XML) but you must serialize it! *But JSON has the best support for AJAX on client and server side*